# Flying with Service Dog to Canada

Tags: air-travel, canada, american-airlines

I’m looking to plan a trip to Banff National Park with my service dog but I was concerned with some of the things I read about import laws regarding service animals that they need to be trained from an accredited dog trainer.

My dog is trained to help me with my mental disability. He had also passed the canine good citizen test. I’m concerned that I will have trouble entering the country. I’ve flown across the US with him but never outside the country.

Can anyone provide guidance on if I will have issues? Mostly concerned about entry and exit from the country.

My dog is also up to date with rabies which I know is a requirement.

Comment: Are you travelling within Canada or from another country?

Answer (score 1):

> they need to be trained from an accredited dog trainer

To be recognized as a assistance dog by the Canadian government, yes, it needs to have been trained and certified as such by a accreditated dog trainer

> If you are bringing a dog to Canada that is not trained and certified by an organization accredited by [Assistance Dogs International (opens in new window)](https://assistancedogsinternational.org/resources/member-search/#member_programs) or the [International Guide Dog Federation (opens in new window)](https://www.igdf.org.uk/closest-dog-guide-providers/), change your selection from "assistance dog" to either "personal" or "commercial" to get the correct import requirements for your situation.

[Bringing animals to Canada: Importing and travelling with pets](https://inspection.canada.ca/importing-food-plants-or-animals/pets/eng/1326600389775/1326600500578) (the exact import rules are in the linked page, not pasting them due to rules being age-dependent)

---

> Mostly concerned about entry and exit from the country.

Canada is a country [free of rabbies, screwworms and foot and mouth disease](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/pet-travel/bring-pet-into-the-united-states/dog-import-pets).

The CDC doesn't apply further restrictions if the dogs have only been in the US and Canada :

> #### Dog from Countries Without High Risk of Dog Rabies
>
> Dogs that have NOT been in a [high-risk country](https://www.cdc.gov/importation/bringing-an-animal-into-the-united-states/high-risk.html) in the past 6 months may enter the United States through any port of entry, and importers are NOT required by CDC to present rabies vaccination documentation. However, when your dog enters the United States, you must provide a written or verbal statement your dog has only been in a country NOT at high risk for at least 6 months or since birth if under 6 months of age. There is no limit to the number of dogs.

So, for rentry in the US, you only need to check the [US Department of Agriculture](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/pet-travel/bring-pet-into-the-united-states/pet-travel-dogs-into-us) page about your state of residence procedures for pet import